# Ask Questions To The Highligted Words?

Tags: questions

Can you help,please?

1. They have been studying **Polish** since November. 
   What they have been studying since November?
2. The **form** must be filled in. 
   What must be filled in?
3. She will retire **in 2012**. 
   When she will retire?
4. The women have drunk **all my whisky**. 
   Who have drunk all my whisky?
5. They are coming to see **us**. 
   What are they doing?

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be **fill out** a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your question, so your highlighted words appear in bold and more evident. Now the answers:

1) What have they been studying since November?

2) What must be filled in?

3) When will she retire?

4) What have the women drunk?

5) Who are they coming to visit?